# Keras - Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Getting this issue (using `Keras` and `Tensorflow`), any help would be greatly appreciated.

My directory is set to be `folder/folder/images` - for both training and testing data.

I made a loop to test the different depths/nb_layers in a `Resnet`, as well as some hyper parameters like learning rate, batch size, etc. The test went from 4, 6, 8, 10 - all the way to 20, then gave me:

> output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y).
>   Found: None

I don't understand why it can work for a handful of the iterations, then fail.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092904/keras-imag) to update keras to 2.0, but was told not to change the version of keras by my boss. I'm on version 1.2.0.

I read [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2971) to convert all labels to a numpy array, but keras documentation states this already happens to labels while using the 'categorical' attribute in flow_from_directory

Then I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/keras-users/MfquYYpZGfo/pz2kvjcFCgAJ) to put my train_generator in a function, then create an infinite while loop and yield the results, but this results in the data to be loaded over and over at the start of the program.  "Found 350 images belonging to 7 classes" (repeated 10 times), which then results in an error

```
"output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x0000000063494BE0>"
```

Here's my stack trace for the original error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('K:/Manufacturing Operations/Yield/Tools_Yield/PythonScripts/AI/ISL_DI/Resnet/resISL_Depth.py',
>   wdir='K:/Manufacturing
>   Operations/Yield/Tools_Yield/PythonScripts/AI/ISL_DI/Resnet')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 714, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\paul.\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 89, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "K:/Manufacturing
>   Operations/Yield/Tools_Yield/PythonScripts/AI/ISL_DI/Resnet/resISL_Depth.py",
>   line 233, in 
>       callbacks=callbacks_list)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\paul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1481, in fit_generator
>       str(generator_output))
>
> ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y,
>   sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None

Here's the code other than vars

```
rep=0
for i in range(retrainings + 1):
    #lr_init = [5, 1, .1, .01]
    while rep != len(layers) - 1:
        lr_init = [5, 1]
        for lr_val in lr_init:


            decay_init = .1
            epochs_drop = 20
            patience=60
            # learning rate schedule
            def step_decay(epoch):
                initial_lrate = lr_val
                drop = 0.1
                epochs_drop = 60
                lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop, math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
                #print('\nLR: {:.6f}\n'.format(lrate))
                return lrate

            momentum_init=0.9
            sgd = SGD(lr=lr_val, decay=decay_init, momentum=momentum_init, nesterov=False)


            ##reduce learning rate when loss has stopped improving
            #lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=np.sqrt(0.1), cooldown=0, patience=5, min_lr=0.5e-6)
            ##stop training when accuracy has stopped improving
            early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, patience=50)
            #csv_logger = CSVLogger('resnet18_cifar10.csv')

            repititions = 3
            #epochs=[105]
            epochs=[200]
            drop_out=[0]
            #batchsize=[2, 4, 8, 10]
            batchsize=[2, 5, 10]
            zoom=[0]
            shear=[0] 
            channelshift=[0]
            featurewise=[False]
            samplewise=[False]
            rotation=[0]

            nb_train_samples = 350
            nb_validation_samples = 140

            colormode='rgb'

             # input image dimensions
            img_width, img_height = 224, 224
            nb_classes=7                                    
            img_channels = 3

            for epoch_val in epochs:
                for dropout_val in drop_out:
                    for batchsize_val in batchsize:
                        for zoom_val in zoom:
                            for shear_val in shear:
                                for channelshift_val in channelshift:
                                    for featurewise_val in featurewise:
                                        for samplewise_val in samplewise:
                                            for rotation_val in rotation:
                                                for r in range(repititions):

                #                                    np.random.seed(7)
                #                                    tf.set_random_seed(7)    

                                                    train_data_dir = basepath + pathlist[0] 
                                                    validation_data_dir = basepath + pathlist[1] 

                                                    #############################################
                                                    #############################################

                                                    params={}    
                                                    params['epochs']=epoch_val
                                                    params['drop_out']=dropout_val
                                                    params['batchsize']=batchsize_val
                                                    params['zoom']=zoom_val
                                                    params['shear']=shear_val
                                                    params['channelshift']=channelshift_val
                                                    params['featurewise']=featurewise_val
                                                    params['samplewise']=samplewise_val
                                                    params['rotation']=rotation_val
                                                    params['lr_init']=lr_val
                                                    params['momentum_init']=momentum_init
                                                    params['decay_init']=decay_init
                                                    params['epochs_drop']=epochs_drop
                                                    params['img_size']=list([img_width,img_height])
                                                    params['patience']=patience                                         

                                                    total = 0
                                                    currentlayer = [i * 2 for i in layers[rep]]
                                                    total = sum(currentlayer) + 2
                                                    savefilename='resnet_' + str(total) + '_BKM_lr_' + str(lr_val) + '_batchSize_' + str(batchsize_val) + '_repition' + str((r+1)) + '_Study' 
                                                    total = 0
                                                    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):

                                                        model = resnet_iter.ResnetBuilder.build_resnet_34((img_channels, img_width, img_height), nb_classes, layers[rep])
                                                        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                                                      optimizer=sgd,
                                                                      metrics=['accuracy'])

                                                        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                                            featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
                                                            samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
                                                            featurewise_std_normalization=featurewise_val,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
                                                            samplewise_std_normalization=samplewise_val,  # divide each input by its std
                                                            zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
                                                            channel_shift_range=channelshift_val, #VGG set to 0
                                                            fill_mode="reflect", #VGG set to reflect
                                                            rotation_range=rotation_val,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
                                                            rescale=1./255, #VGG set to 1./255
                                                            width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width) - VGG set to 0
                                                            height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height) - VGG set to 0
                                                            shear_range=shear_val, #VGG set to 0
                                                            zoom_range=zoom_val, #VGG set to 0.1
                                                            horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
                                                            vertical_flip=True)  # randomly flip images VGG set to True

                                                        test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

                                                        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                            train_data_dir,
                                                            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                            batch_size=batchsize_val,
                                                            shuffle=True,
                                                            color_mode=colormode,
                                                            class_mode='categorical')

                                                        validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                            validation_data_dir,
                                                            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                            batch_size=batchsize_val,
                                                            shuffle=True,
                                                            color_mode=colormode,
                                                            class_mode='categorical')

                                                        lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
                                                        callbacks_list = [lrate, early_stopper]

                                                        try:
                                                            A=model.fit_generator(
                                                                train_generator,
                                                                samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
                                                                nb_epoch=epoch_val,
                                                                validation_data=validation_generator,
                                                                nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples,
                                                                callbacks=callbacks_list)
                                                        except:
                                                            print("train_generator: " + train_generator)
                                                            print("train_data_dir: " + train_data_dir)
                                                            files=os.listdir(train_data_dir)
                                                            print(len(files))
```

Comment: I think debugging is your best option. Instead of using `fit_generator`, use `train_on_batch()`. Each batch can be fetched from the generator by doing `x, y = train_generator.next()`. Check which batch gives you an error. Also, for repeatable results, you can set a random seed using `np.random.seed()`.